# How to multiply two 4-D tensors in Pytorch (implementing Self Attention from paper Attention is all you need)

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, transformer-model

I am trying to learn how to create a [SelfAttention with Heads](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/self-attention-in-nlp/) layer in `Pytorch`. Below is the code which is done using `torch.einsum()`. I am curious how it would look without the function. I have found out that it'll need `torch.bmm` but I'm not sure how.

```
class SelfAttention(nn.module):
    def __init__(self, embed_size:int, num_heads:int):
        '''
        https://lilianweng.github.io/lil-log/assets/images/transformer.png
        https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U0s0f995w14
        '''
        super().__init__()
        assert embed_size // num_heads == 0 , "'embed_size' or Embedding Dimension should be perfectly divisible my 'num_heads_parts'"
        self.embed_size = embed_size
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        self.head_size = self.embed_size // self.num_heads # Embedding is divided into num_heads parts so that each head has same dimension. Dimension of Each Head

        self.key_linear = nn.Linear(self.head_size, self.head_size) # Keys will be multiplied to this weight matrix
        self.query_linear = nn.Linear(self.head_size, self.head_size) # Queries will be multiplied to this weight matrix
        self.value_linear = nn.Linear(self.head_size, self.head_size) # Values will be multiplied to this weight matrix

        self.final_fully_connected = nn.Linear(self.embed_size, self.embed_size) # OR in other terms, nn.Linear(self.num_heads * self.head_size, self.embed_size)
        # Each head's final output will come into this Layer giving a final vector of the size of embedding

    
    def forward(self, key,query,value, mask):
        '''
        For Encoder - Decoder :: Query's next word is dependent on the the words already generated + the attention given to each word in the input sentence
        key: Batch of the sentence we have given as INPUT
        query: Batch of Target Sentences

        key, query and values are batches of sentences of shape [No of samples, Words in each sentence, Embedding Dimension of Each Word]
        '''
        N = key.shape[0] # Number of samples which should be equal in all the key, queries and values
        key_len, query_len, value_len = key.shape[1], query.shape[1], value.shape[1] # number of tokens OR words == length of each sentence 

        assert key_len == value_len, "Key and Value lrngth must be same" # Look at the second einsum where key_len dimension by common "l"

        # Split the Embeddings of key, query and values in [No of samples, Length of each sentence, No of Heads, Dimension of each head]
        key = key.reshape(N, key_len, self.num_heads, self.head_size)
        query = query.reshape(N, query_len, self.num_heads, self.head_size)
        value = value.reshape(N, value_len, self.num_heads, self.head_size)

        # Look for each block of "Scaled Dot Product Attention" in the image https://lilianweng.github.io/lil-log/assets/images/transformer.png

        # finds out the MATMUL as -> Go each word given in our target, how much ATTENTION do we have to pay for each word in our source
        MATMUL = torch.einsum('nqhd,nkhd->nhqk', [query, key])  # Output is (No of samples, No of heads, query Length, Key Length)

        # --------- n: Axis for no of samples , q: axis for sentence length in QUERY, k: axis for sentence length in KEY, h: Axis for number of heads, d: Dimension of each head ---------
       # MATMUL has a shape [No of samples, Number of heads, Query length, Key Length]

        SCALE = MATMUL / torch.sqrt(self.embed_size)

        if mask is not None: # If mask is given, means we want to cover the value at a particular place inside MATMUL, then keep its value as negative infinity or close to it
            SCALE = SCALE.masked_fill(mask == 0, float('-1e-30')) # When a place inside MASK is 0, means we want to cover it. So fill the particular place inside ENERGY as -infinity
        
        SOFTMAX = torch.softmax(SCALE, dim = 3) # Softmax the scores according to the last axis

        # Now Multiply the Normalized  SOFTMAX to the Value -> Long arrow coming from the beginning in the image given

        MATMUL = torch.einsum('nhql,nlhd->nqhd',[SOFTMAX, value]) # original 'nhqk' is replaced by 'nhql' because k == v == l
        MATMUL = MATMUL.reshape(N,query_len,self.embed_size) # embed_size = No of heads * Dimension of each head we need to reshape because we have our Original Embedding fixed

        return self.final_fully_connected(MATMUL)
```

This is what I'm trying to build as exactly given in the figure
[image]

This is the formula for `Scaled Dot Product`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a standard matrix multiplication (`bcik,bckj->bc` since here the channel dimension differs). So I don't believe you can do that with [`matmul`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.matmul.html).
Indeed the operation performed here is `nqhd,nkhd->nhqk`, which means one dimension (subscript `d`) is reduced while operating over cross dimensions on the channel axes (subscripts `q` and `k`).

Explicitly what happens in an einstein summation is an accumulation of products, here in *pseudocode*:

```
res = zeros(N, H, Q, K)
for n, q, k, h, d in NxQxKxHxD: # cartesian product over all possible dimensions
    res[n, h, q, k] += query[n, q, h, d]*key[n, k, h, d]
```

*Side note: `torch.bmm` has identical behavior in terms of operation. Unlike `torch.matmul`, it doesn't provide broadcasting.*

Comment: Could you please give an example of how it would look like with `.bmm` had I not used the `.einsum`?

Comment: @Deshwal What I was trying to explain in my answer is that you can't perform this operation with simple matrix multiplication.